# contact forms not working on site

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I'm currently working on this site:
[link to site](http://www.skipsaviano.com/contact.html)

and the form does not seem to be working. When you submit it always goes to the error page. I also tried this site on a windows server (not sure if that would make a difference) and the form is working fine.

here is the code i'm using...

```
            <?php

            // get posted data into local variables

            $EmailTo = "***@***.com";
            $Subject = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Subject'])); 
            $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
            $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
            $Address = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Address'])); 
            $City = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City'])); 
            $State = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['State'])); 
            $Zip = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Zip'])); 
            $Phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Phone'])); 
            $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); /*
            $Sign = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Sign'])); 
            $Volunteer = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Volunteer'])); 
            $Walk = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Walk'])); 
            $Coffee = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Coffee'])); 
            $Calls = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Calls'])); 
            $Donate = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Donate'])); */
            $EmailFromName = $Name;
            $EmailFromAddress = $Email;

            // validation
            $validationOK=true;
            if (!$validationOK) {
              print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
              exit;
            }

            // prepare email body text
            $Body = "";
            $Body .= "This Email was sent from the Saviano for State Representative Website, contact page.";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Name: ";
            $Body .= $Name;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Address: ";
            $Body .= $Address;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "City: ";
            $Body .= $City;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "State: ";
            $Body .= $State;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Zip: ";
            $Body .= $Zip;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Phone: ";
            $Body .= $Phone;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Email: ";
            $Body .= $Email;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Subject: ";
            $Body .= $Subject;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Message: ";
            $Body .= $Message;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";/*
            $Body .= "Sign: ";
            $Body .= $Sign;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Volunteer: ";
            $Body .= $Volunteer;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Walk: ";
            $Body .= $Walk;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Coffee: ";
            $Body .= $Coffee;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Calls: ";
            $Body .= $Calls;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Donate: ";
            $Body .= $Donate;*/
            $Body .= "\n";




            // send email 
            $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFromName <$EmailFromAddress>");

            // redirect to success page 
            if ($success){
              print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=thanks.html\">";
            }
            else{
              print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
            }
            ?>
```

p.s. the forms on the survey and volunteer page don't work also but work on the windows server.

Comment: i also tried the error reporting at the top of the php file and nothing is showing up.

Comment: Try using `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: just tried that and no solution to the problem.

Comment: Ask your server admin to check is sending outbound emails is enabled for anonymous accounts on your server.

Comment: just to see if that makes a difference, i changed the from email address to the same one as the 'to' email address and that didn't make a change.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html): Header fields are terminated by CRLF.

Try this (I added "\r\n" at the end):

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFromName <$EmailFromAddress>\r\n");
```

Comment: what code should i use to get proper error reporting? when you submit it just goes to send.php and then to the error page. i'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: also do you think anything should be changed in php.ini?

Comment: Add this to the beginning of send.php: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` It will display all PHP errors directly in the page. I think you will see an error related to the mail() function.

Comment: i saw it flash for a sec that emailto is undefined on line 95. but i have it declared in my code. :(

Comment: In the code you posted, $EmailTo is defined on the first line of code. Do you still have this line of code? For easier debugging I suggest temporarily replacing the 2 "<meta>" lines with `print 'success'` and `print 'error'`.

Comment: this is going to sound so wierd but the form is working now without even making any changes. something must have updated or refreshed on the server, thats all i can presume. thanks for everybodys help!